# Kotlin coroutines: wrap cassandra synchronous usage vs translate asynchronous usage

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

This question probably applies to other libraries as well, but using Cassandra as a specific example to try to ensure I'm asking an answerable question:

With Kotlin, I can either use Cassandra's async methods, then wrap them with the [ListenableFuture](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-guava/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.guava/com.google.common.util.concurrent.-listenable-future/await.html) integration, **or** I can use Cassandra's synchronous methods and wrap their usage with a suspending method and launch/async.

I'm guessing that the better technique is to use a library's existing async methods, presuming that would more easily avoid deadlocks and be faster, but I'm speculating and am new to coroutines.

Is this an obvious answer for people more experienced with coroutines, or are there specific areas where "it depends"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the internal details of the library you are using and on your performance/scalability goals:

- If your library is *internally asynchronous* then it would be always advisable to use it via its native asynchronous API. Disclaimer: I have no idea how Cassandra is structured internally (sync or async).
- If your library is internally synchronous/blocking (and most legacy libraries are), then it depends:

  - If your application is IO-bound (reads/writes a lot of bytes to/from
    network/disk) and you are optimizing it for throughput (maximizing
    number of bytes processing on large batch loads), then, as a rule of
    thumb, you'll be better of using synchronous/blocking APIs.
  - If your application is memory-bound and you want to scale it to more 
    concurrent connections/requests, then, as a rule of thumb, you'll be 
    better of using asynchronous APIs.